# Can I prevent embedded view from putting a database on the workspace?

Tags: lotus-notes

I have two databases, A and B. I want to surface a view from B into A. I can do this using an embedded view in an outline or a form and it works fine.

But I do not want database B put on a user's workspace. If I add it and the user opens a doc or opens the view, then it puts that db on the workspace.

Is there a way around this? What if I embed an Xpage?

Answer (score 2):

That's a built-in behavior of Lotus Notes and unfortunately there's no way to turn that behavior off.

As an alternative you could write an Agent that pulls the data in from Database B into Database A, and then just display that data within a Database A view.

Comment: I really don't want to write yet another agent to populate data. Kind of why I am trying to do this. I determined I *can* use an Xpage in database in A that gets data from B, and it doesn't put the bookmark on the workspace. The only issue I would like to overcome is not to have the link open a new tab, but to open it in the content frame of the navigator. Is that possible? And thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: I would ask that follow up question as a separate question in StackOverflow, so more people will see it.  I'm not that familiar with XPages so I can't offer any guidance there.

Comment: I think that if you used the content frame as a URL, accessing the data via HTTP, I think you could do it that way. I don't think you could have XPiNC in a frame, but using browser access might work.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken already said that it is a built-in behavior. You can try to programmatically remove the database icon. This [Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097270) describes it.

```
@Command([AddDatabase]; "Server Name":"DatabaseB.nsf");
@Command([WindowWorkspace]);
@Command([FileDatabaseRemove]);
```

I haven't tried it myself, but you can put this code on close of form of embedded view. Also, its **not** possible to remove a database icon from the Notes client workspace using LotusScript, JavaScript, or Notes API.

Answer (score 0):

It works as Naveen describes it. However, even if you manage to clean up the icon, in Notes there is a built-in fault when using an embedded view from another database.

The problem is -- you cannot use the traditional Notes templates because the link to the source database of the embedded view is hard-coded using the replicaid. So if you pull a template from your design and create a new database for production, the embedded view will still point to your test database.

I have used this configuration, but then each time you deploy a new template you need to modify design, so that it points to the correct database. It can be programmed for example by using DXL export/import but is not a trivial Notes deployment any more.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options here: computed text to display the contents of the view using HTML, creating an Xpage that displays the view, or some AJAX to get the data and display in HTML.

**Computed text to display the view**

This is relatively simple. Add computed text, set to use pass-through HTML, that does a DbColumn on a new view in the source database. Either add a hidden column at the end of the existing view or create a new, single column view that has the HTML for a single row in the view.

For the computed text, just a simple formula:

```
"<table>" + @DbColumn( "Notes" : "NoCache" ; "MyServer/Company" : "SourceDatabase.nsf" ; "HTMLview" ; 1) + "</table>"
```

Then, for the column formula, use something like this:

```
"<tr><td>" + PartName + "</td><td>" + PartNumber  + "</td><td>" + Price + "</td></tr>"
```

**XPage for view**

Just create the XPage with a simple view, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

<xp:viewPanel rows="30" id="viewPanel1">
         <xp:this.facets>
                 <xp:pager partialRefresh="true" layout="Previous Group Next" xp:key="headerPager" id="pager1">
                 </xp:pager>
         </xp:this.facets>
         <xp:this data>
                 <xp:dominoView var="view1" viewName="COPApprovals"></xp:dominoView>
         </xp:this.data>
         <xp:viewColumn columnName="$11" id="viewColumn1" style="font-weight:bold;color:rgb(0,0,160)">
         </xp:viewColumn>
         <xp:viewColumn columnName="$10" id="viewColumn2" style="font-weight:bold;color:rgb(0,64,0)">
         </xp:viewColumn>
         <xp:viewcolumn columnName="$12" id="viewColumn3">
         </xp:viewColumn>
</xp:viewPanel>

</xp:view>
```

**AJAX**

A good intro to using AJAX to display Notes data can be found in Scott Good's AJAX name-picker. I've built a number of views and picklists using that format. The laptop that has the modified designs is on the fritz right now. If I get access again, I will post samples.

Hope you get some ideas there.